# Let z1=x1+iy1 and z2=x2+iy2 be two complex numbers. The dot product of z1 and z2 is defined by <z1,z2>=x1x2+y1y2

Tags: vector-spaces

Let z1=x1+iy1 and z2=x2+iy2 be two complex numbers. The dot product of z1 and z2 is defined by z1,z2=x1x2+y1y2 For non zero z1 and z2

**prove the following**

$$<z1,z2> =|z1||z2|\cosθ ~~\hbox{where $0≤θ≤π$ is the angle between z1 and z2.}$$

$$⟨z1,z2⟩ = Re(z1¯¯¯z2)$$ 
$$⟨z1,z2⟩ = 12(z1¯¯¯z2+z1z2¯¯¯)$$
$$z1⊥z2⟺θ=π2$$

Answer (score 1):

The proof that $$z_1 \cdot z_2 = ||z_1||||z_2||\cos\theta$$ is too cumbersome for me to write out, so feel free to view it here: [Link to Proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product)

If $z_1 \perp z_2$, then the distance between the vectors from the origin to them is $0$. So, the dot product is $0$. This gives us $$\cos\theta = 0,$$ $$\theta = 90.$$

Comment: prove  first second and 3rd

Comment: @maha I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: i want to prove all